# Background-Color grey, rather than transparent

Tags: html, css

So when I try to remove the background-color attribute, the background stay a grey sort of color, rather than becoming transparent. Code:

CSS:

```
    #contact-form button[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 100px 0 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 372px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#contact-form button[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2D2D2D;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any HTML we can look at? My guess is that there is some other conflicting CSS, or you are incorrectly targeting the button so the default style is being applied.

Comment: @blackandorangecat It was connecting with the HTML I know because I can change the background to any color put I couldn't make it transparent.

Comment: If you want to make the button hidden until moused over, just add `background:transparent;` to the first CSS rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `background:transparent;` instead of `background:#fff;` as this changes the color of background to "white", it do not turn the background transparent, it might help. And as @blackandorangecat said, there might be other conflicting CSS available, please go through your code and try removing it.

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-color&preval=transparent for background CSS properties

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the button hidden until moused over, just add `background:transparent;` to the first CSS rule. I added the form background to make it clear how it works.

```css
#contact-form button[type="submit"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 372px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: transparent; /* This is all that was needed */
}

#contact-form button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #2D2D2D;
}

form {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form id="contact-form">

  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Click Me!</button>

</form>
```